Conda debug/build patches not applying due to FileNotFoundError
I'm trying to create some conda recipes that have patches to some of the build files in them. Something like:
source:
  - url: https://path/to/some/repo.tar.gz
  - patches:
    - some.p0.patch

where some.p0.patch modifies a file inside the given repository, ala
diff --git some/path/Makefile some/path/Makefile
index 9bc26c5..b1b8287 100755
--- some/path/Makefile
+++ some/path/Makefile
# diff contents, generated with git diff --no-prefix some/path/Makefile

When I then run either conda build or conda debug it produces the following error:
Downloading source to cache: 9b26e5c36a84e726bf5e4b3e40c2fbe760581417_aaff0b9835.tar.gz
Downloading https://path/to/some/repo.tar.gz
Success
Extracting download
Copying /home/simonrose/git/recipes/some-recipe/src to /home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/conda-bld/debug_1722428483898/work/
Applying patch: /home/simonrose/git/recipes/some-recipe/recipe/some.p0.patch
Patch level ambiguous, selecting least deep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/bin/conda-debug", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_debug.py", line 102, in execute
    activation_string = api.debug(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 681, in debug
    run_build(target_metadata, stats={}, provision_only=True)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2419, in build
    try_download(m, no_download_source=False, raise_error=True)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 762, in try_download
    source.provide(metadata)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 1114, in provide
    apply_one_patch(src_dir, metadata.path, patch, metadata.config, git)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 974, in apply_one_patch
    patch_attributes = _get_patch_attributes(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 851, in _get_patch_attributes
    copy_to_be_patched_files(src_dir, tmp_src_dir, files)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 849, in copy_to_be_patched_files
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src_dir, file), dst)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/shutil.py", line 475, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/lib/python3.12/shutil.py", line 260, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/conda-bld/debug_1722428483898/work/some/path/Makefile'

As stated above, the file to be patched definitely exists in the repository. Moreover,
if I immediately run ls /home/simonrose/miniforge3/envs/require_test/conda-bld/debug_1722428483898/work/some/path/Makefile then it shows that the file exists.
I had hoped that conda debug would hep with, you know, debugging this, but that also fails in setting up the debug environment (including applying the patch) before giving me access to it.
This has somewhat forced me to so far modify the build script to apply the patches using cat/sed/pick your favorite tool; for relatively small changes this is fine, but for more complex ones this is of course untenable.
Is there something obvious I am missing here? This is a very odd issue...
Some additional info:

This is running on a Centos7 VM hosted on an x86 Mac
Conda version is:

$ conda --version
conda 24.3.0
$ conda build --version
conda-build 24.5.1

